# how to get pylint status code in python venv

Tags: python, pylint, python-venv

I created python venv(virtual environment) . And I ran blew command to get pylint result.

```
>pylint  --errors-only --output-format=pylint2junit.JunitReporter ./code/XXX/TTTT.py > PylintTest.xml
```

Then I want to get the status code of pylint.

```
>echo $?
```

$?

It does not return the code.

Comment: Use this to get return code:
echo %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: @Code_10 wonderful!! how could you know this?

Comment: Through stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get response of previous command you executed, you can run -

`echo %ERRORLEVEL%`